# Enable Single Sign On for some users

Tags: single-sign-on

I want to enable single sign on for some users, but don't see the 'is Single Sign on Enabled' checkbox under 'System Permissions' on the permission set that I created, neither do I see it on the Profile under 'System Permissions'

So i have to contact Salesforce or do I have to configure some settings in Salesforce to enable the 'Single Sign On' for some users?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you need to have "Delegated authentication" permission enabled in order to see "Is single sign on user" permission.From Summer'20 release you no longer need to reach out to support to get it enabled as System administrator can enable it.Please follow the steps as below:

Your Name > Setup > Look for Single Sign-On Settings in Quick Find > Under Delegated Authentication, select Disable login with Salesforce credentials

Please refer this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334713&type=1&mode=1) for more information.

Thank you!